# How to disable built-in PDF viewer in chromedriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver, pdf-viewer, chrome-options

Download should start when I click on the PDF download link but currently, pdf is open in a new tab and there is a download option [image]

currently my config:

```
$chromeOption->addArguments([
        "--disable-gpu"
]);

$prefs = [
            "download.default_directory"         => 'I set the download path here',
            "savefile.default_directory"         => 'I set the download path here',
            "download.prompt_for_download"       => false,
            "download.directory_upgrade"         => true,
            "download.always_open_pdf_externally"=> true,
            "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally" => true,
            "savefile.type"=> 1,
            "plugins.plugins_disabled"           => ["Chrome PDF Viewer"]
];
```

My ChromeDriver Version 114.0.5735.90

As shown in the attached picture, when I click on the Open button download starts but I need the download automatically when I click on the PDF link and this attached picture should not appear

Comment: Update the question with the test based HTML of the element.

Comment: Add this to your $prefs ```"pdfjs.disabled" => true``` - see if that helps, you seem to have everything else you need

Comment: thanks, @djmonki   `"pdfjs.disabled" => true` working fine on Firefox but not working on Google chrome

Comment: Ah yes pdfjs is a mozilla library - I'll keep looking